# Can NagiosXi generate daily report for server performance (CPU, Memory and Hard Disk usage)?

Tags: nagios

Can NagiosXi generate daily report for server performance (CPU, Memory and Hard Disk usage)?

I'm looking way to have daily server performance report for server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Enterprise verion, you can schedule a dashboard with any metrics to be sent with an interval per email. Consult the Nagios forums for more information..

https://support.nagios.com/forum